# Laravel get total time workerd by employee between two dates using carbonInterval or carbon php

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-6, php-carbon

i have time shifts which are assigned to the user. Suppose a night shift starting time is `21-00-00 pm of one july` and its ending time is `03-00-00 am of 2nd July`. Now i want to get total time a employee worked by adding start time to end time which is equal to `6 hours` and i should get six hours. I have tried following code which is working fine for `current date` like it will give me exact `6 hours` if start time is equal to `15-00-00 pm of 1 july` to `21-00-00 pm of 1 july` but it will fail when shifts exists between two dates as i mentioned above.

```
    $attendance_start_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($shift->start_time);

   $attendance_end_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($shift->end_time);

   $total_attendance_time=$attendance_end_time->diffInSeconds($attendance_start_time,true);

   \Carbon\CarbonInterval::seconds($total_attendance_time)->cascade()->forHumans()
```

i am expecting six hours but it is giving me following result

```
18 hours
```

i want exact `six` hours

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fully solve your problem, but check out this :

```php
\Carbon\CarbonInterval::seconds(4100)->cascade()->forHumans(['aUnit' => true]);
```

UPD:
It might be this solution will work in your case, but make sure that you have tested all of the edge-cases:

```php
    $startTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-07-02 19:00');

    $endTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-07-02 19:30');

    $diff = $startTime->diffInSeconds($endTime);

    if ($endTime->greaterThanOrEqualTo($endTime) && ! $endTime->isSameDay($startTime)) {
        $diff = $startTime->diffInSeconds($endTime->addDay());
    }

    $humanReadable = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::seconds($diff)->cascade()->forHumans(['aUnit' => true]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but this solution is not working if start time is 19-00-00 pm and and end time is time 24-00-00 pm then it t will give exact 5 hours but if end time is 03-00-00 am it will give me 16 hours , in a nutshull this solution is not working

Comment: Please checkout updated version